# Why is Throwing NullRefrenceException the prefered behaviour when foreach gets a NULL item?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I understand that the foreach function needs to get an IEnumerable from the item it's trying to loop over. But why?

In my head there seems to be way more situations where you would want the behavior to be that it doesn't trigger at all.

I also understand that you can do;

```
foreach (var h in file.Headers ?? new())
{
    //do stuff
}
```

or;

```
listOfItems?.ForEach(item => // ... )
{
    //do stuff
}
```

So basically, why is the current behavior the preferred behavior? Is it like this in most other languages as well? Is it because of efficiency?

Comment: I think that's because a null-check would be a side effect of foreach and would violate the single responsible principle

Comment: For me it's totally reasonable that a NRE is thrown if the sequence is `null`. If the code behaved as if the sequence was empty, this would probably hide errors in the code. If I do a foreach without null-checking the sequence, I surely did not expect it to be `null` here, so the exception is correct.

Comment: It's also why, as an implementer, it's often kinder to return `Enumerable.Empty<T>` rather than `null`.

Comment: @RenéVogt that makes a lot of sense, especially with what Damien said. It's much smarter to make sure it returns empty when something did not go wrong, so you can catch an error of NRE if something did go wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @Jak: with that argument you could ask why there is a `NullReferenceException` at all? The runtime could just swallow it and continue. That's not the way this language was designed. We want an error if we use a null reference. You can always avoid that it's null in the first place. It's a different behavior if you treat `null` like an empty sequence in general.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That was actually my question and your answer clarified it for me even more! Thank you :-)